# patametric ph model

Tags: r, regression

I need to get the parameters of covariates and Hazard Rate in a model that assumes the baseline hazard is the hazard rate of a log-normal. I used survreg(), but I log-normal don't have PH interpretation. I'm not sure how to translate the coefficient in the result to get parameters and HR. Please help. THANK YOU.

```
survreg(Surv(survival, DIED)~AGE+GENDER+PLATE+NEUTRO+NIH,dist="lognormal",data=IMRAWandIST)
```

Call:

```
Value Std. Error     z         p
```

(Intercept)  9.26056   0.339816 27.25 1.59e-163

```
AGE         -0.03707   0.004647 -7.98  1.51e-15
GENDERM     -0.39260   0.121338 -3.24  1.21e-03
Log(scale)   0.47260   0.031396 15.05  3.31e-51
```

Scale= 1.6

Log Normal distribution
Loglik(model)= -4625.3   Loglik(intercept only)= -4699.6
    Chisq= 148.54 on 5 degrees of freedom, p= 0 
Number of Newton-Raphson Iterations: 4 
n=917 (28 observations deleted due to missingness)

Comment: Could you provide more details--maybe an example of the command you used and the output you received?